# Pointers in Common Lisp

Tags: pointers, lisp, common-lisp

I want to save a reference (pointer) to a part of some Data I saved in another variable:

```
(let ((a (list 1 2 3)))
  (let ((b (car (cdr a)))) ;here I want to set b to 2, but it is set to a copy of 2
    (setf b 4))
  a) ;evaluates to (1 2 3) instead of (1 4 2)
```

I could use macros, but then there would ever be much code to be executed if I want to change some Data in the middle of a list and I am not very flexible:

```
(defparameter *list* (create-some-list-of-arrays))
(macrolet ((a () '(nth 1000 *list*)))
  (macrolet ((b () `(aref 100 ,(a))))
    ;; I would like to change the macro a here if it were possible
    ;; but then b would mean something different
    (setf (b) "Hello")))
```

Is it possible, to create a variable as a reference and not as a copy?

Comment: What is wrong with (let ((a (list 1 2 3))) (setf (second a) 4) a) ?

Comment: I highly recommend reading this http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/variables.html and focus on the details of values, variables and places. Sorry if you are not a newbie to the language, but if you are then do remember that mapping techniques from other languages wont necessarily give you good or fast code.

Comment: You'll probably be interested in the answer to [How do I globally change a variable value within function in lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19491275/1281433) which discusses C pointers, indirection through structures (including cons cells), generalized references, and simulating C-style pointers.  The question isn't quite the same, but I think the answer might be what you need.

Comment: The first code snippet there is undefined behaviour. lists defined using quote are constants and the effect of modifying a constant is undefined. If you want to modify the list create it with list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
cl-user> (let ((a '(1 2 3)))
           (let ((b (car (cdr a))))
             (setf b 4))
           a)
;Compiler warnings :
;   In an anonymous lambda form: Unused lexical variable B
(1 2 3)
```

A `cons` cell is a pair of pointers. `car` dereferences the first, and `cdr` dereferences the second. Your list is effectively

```
  a -> [ | ] -> [ | ] -> [ | ] -> NIL
        |        |        |
        1        2        3
```

Up top where you're defining `b`, `(cdr a)` gets you that second arrow. Taking the `car` of that dereferences the first pointer of that second cell and hands you its value. In this case, `2`. If you want to change the value of that pointer, you need to `setf` it rather than its value.

```
cl-user> (let ((a '(1 2 3)))
           (let ((b (cdr a)))
             (setf (car b) 4))
           a)
(1 4 3)
```

Answer (score 4):

If all you need is some syntactic sugar, try [`symbol-macrolet`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_symbol.htm#symbol-macrolet):

```
(let ((a (list 1 2 3 4)))
  (symbol-macrolet ((b (car (cdr a))))
    (format t "~&Old: ~S~%" b)
    (setf b 'hello)
    (format t "~&New: ~S~%" b)))
```

Note, that this is strictly a compile-time thing. Anywhere (in the scope of the `symbol-macrolet`), where `b` is used as variable, it is expanded into `(car (cdr a))` at compile time. As Sylwester already stated, there are no "references" in Common Lisp.

I wouldn't recommend this practice for general use, though.

And by the way: never change quoted data. Using `(setf (car ...) ...)` (and similar) on a constant list literal like `'(1 2 3)` will have undefined consequences.

Answer (score 1):

Building on what Baggers suggested. Not exactly what you are looking for but you can define setf-expanders to create 'accessors'. So lets say your list contains information about people in the for of (first-name last-name martial-status) and when someone marries you can update it as:

```
(defun marital-status (person)
  (third person))

(defun (setf marital-status) (value person)
  (setf (third person) value))

(let ((person (list "John" "Doe" "Single")))
  (setf (marital-status person) "Married")
  person)
;; => ("John" "Doe" "Married")
```