# How to create an array of function pointers in Common Lisp?

Tags: common-lisp, ansi-common-lisp

I have a program that requires having a series of interchangeable functions.

In c++ I can do a simple `typedef` statement. Then I can call upon on a function in that list with `function[variable]`. How can I do this in Common Lisp?

Comment: you can put lambda in hash-table, no need to define anything. then you can `funcall` it.

Comment: it would be nice if you added a (pseudo)code sample.

Comment: I was sure in next 5 minutes some sds, sylwester or barmar would come and post 3 screens long answer that will again teach me something :)

Answer (score 4):

In Common Lisp **everything** is a object value, functions included. `(lambda (x) (* x x))` returns a function value. The value is the address where the function resides or something similar so just having it in a list, vector og hash you can fetch that value and call it. Here is an example using lists:

```
;; this creates a normal function in the function namespace in the current package
(defun sub (a b)
  (- a b))

;; this creates a function object bound to a variable
(defparameter *hyp* (lambda (a b) (sqrt (+ (* a a) (* b b)))))

;; this creates a lookup list of functions to call
(defparameter *funs* 
  (list (function +) ; a standard function object can be fetched by name with function
        #'sub        ; same as function, just shorter syntax
        *hyp*))      ; variable *hyp* evaluates to a function

;; call one of the functions (*hyp*)
(funcall (third *funs*) 
         3
         4)
; ==> 5

;; map over all the functions in the list with `3` and `4` as arguments
(mapcar (lambda (fun)
          (funcall fun 3 4))
        *funs*)
; ==> (7 -1 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

A vector of functions, where we take one and call it:

```
CL-USER 1 > (funcall (aref (vector (lambda (x) (+ x 42))
                                   (lambda (x) (* x 42))
                                   (lambda (x) (expt x 42)))
                           1)
                     24)
1008
```

Answer (score 2):

The already given answers having provided plenty of code, I'd like to complement with a bit of theory. An important distinction among languages is whether or not they treat functions as [first-class citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen). When they do, they are said to support [first-class functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function). Common Lisp [does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp#Functions), C and C++ [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48092176/why-are-functions-not-considered-first-class-citizens-in-c). Therefore, Common Lisp offers considerably greater latitude than C/C++ in the use of functions. In particular (see other answers for code), one creates arrays of functions in Common Lisp (through [lambda-expressions](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node64.html)) much in the same way as arrays of any other object. As for 'pointers' in Common Lisp, you may want to have a look [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Address_of_a_variable#Common_Lisp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22835755/pointers-in-common-lisp) for a flavour of how things are done the Common Lisp way.