# Usage of DEFSETF

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

It is just really hard to understand from a standard description, so:

For instance, I'm trying to set a k-th position of some list (ls) to a specific value. Even have a function of my own, that gives acces to k-th elt.

```
(defun kth-elt (lst k)
 (cond ((> 0 k) nil)
  ((equal 0 k) (car lst))
  ((< 0 k) (kth-elt (cdr lst) (- k 1))))).
```

Also made a function, that updates that value.

```
 (defun kth-upd (lst k new)
  (cond ((> 0 k) nil)
    ((equal 0 k) (setf  (car lst) new))
    ((< 0 k) (kth-upd (cdr lst) (- k 1) new))))
```

Now i can actually use that, but i wanna understand the difference between it and DEFSETF. Also I still do not understand. how to "teach" defsetf to use these. Thx for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your definitions, it is simply:

```
(defsetf kth-elt kth-upd)
```

Instead of using `kth-upd`, you can now use `kth-elt` and `(setf kth-elt)`.
For example:

```
(let ((list (copy-list '(a b c d e f))))
  (setf (kth-elt list 3) nil)
  list)

=> (A B C NIL E F)
```

But the real benefits of using [`SETF`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/a_setf.htm) consistently is that you can combine this setter with other ones. Just consider incrementing a value:

```
(let ((list (make-list 10 :initial-element 0)))
  (incf (kth-elt list 3))
  (incf (kth-elt list 5) 20)
  list)

=> (0 0 0 1 0 20 0 0 0 0)
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24095208/124319) from Rainer Joswig for more background on *places* and SETF.

### Setf expander

Note that you are doing the list traversal twice: you first get the current value, then computes the new one; only then, you store the new value, starting from the beginning of the list:

```
  0: (KTH-ELT (0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0) 3)
    1: (KTH-ELT (0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0) 2)
      2: (KTH-ELT (0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0) 1)
        3: (KTH-ELT (0 0 0 0 0 0 0) 0)
        3: KTH-ELT returned 0
      2: KTH-ELT returned 0
    1: KTH-ELT returned 0
  0: KTH-ELT returned 0
  0: (KTH-UPD (0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0) 3 1)
    1: (KTH-UPD (0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0) 2 1)
      2: (KTH-UPD (0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0) 1 1)
        3: (KTH-UPD (0 0 0 0 0 0 0) 0 1)
        3: KTH-UPD returned 1
      2: KTH-UPD returned 1
    1: KTH-UPD returned 1
  0: KTH-UPD returned 1
```

This can also be seen by macroexpansion:

```
(incf (kth-elt list 3))
```

... is macroexpanded as:

```
(LET* ((#:LIST796 LIST) (#:NEW1 (+ 1 (KTH-ELT #:LIST796 3))))
  (KTH-UPD #:LIST796 3 #:NEW1))
```

Another possible approach might be to use [`DEFINE-SETF-EXPANDER`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/m_defi_3.htm):

```
(define-setf-expander kth (list index)
  (alexandria:with-gensyms (store cell)
    (values `(,cell)
            `((nthcdr ,index ,list))
            `(,store)
            `(setf (car ,cell) ,store)
            `(car ,cell))))
```

The function returns 5 different code parts that can be assembled to access and modify a place. `cell` and `store` are local variables introduced using [`GENSYM`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_gensym.htm).

The variable `cell` (i.e. the variable named after the fresh symbol bound to `cell`) will be bound to `(nthcdr index list)`. `store` contains the value to set in the place. Here, it will be put at the appropriate place by using `(setf (car cell) store)`. Also, the existing value in the place is `(car cell)`. As you can see, we need to manipulate, under the hood, the cons cell we mutate (of course, an error is raised with empty lists).
The macroexpansion for `(incf (kth list 3))` is:

```
(LET* ((#:CELL798 (NTHCDR 3 LIST)) (#:STORE797 (+ 1 (CAR #:CELL798))))
  (SETF (CAR #:CELL798) #:STORE797))
```

The setter function knows how to access the place that holds the value we want to change, and can change it directly, which is more efficent than just a pair of reader/writer functions.

### Remark about mutability

SETF is designed around mutable data. If you write an accessor for a key/value store on the network, so that `(remote host key)` will connect and retrieve a value, and `(setf (remote host key) value)` sends the new value back, then it is not guaranteed that the remote value is always updated when `(remote host key)` is used as an intermediate place.

For example, if the value is a list, `(push val (remote host key))` will push on the local list created on your host, there is no obligation for `setf` to actually ensure the result is sent back to the network when it is part of a larger expression. That allows SETF to be efficient by mutating places, at the small cost of requiring you to be more explicit. In the preceding example, you have to write `(setf (remote host key) new-list)` directly (not as a nested place) to effectively send the new data back.

Comment: Unfortunately, the whole thing about setf was initial problem. Trying to use it this way, I got:
`(defparameter ls '(1 2 3 4 5))`

`(setf (kth-elt ls 4) 11)`

`; in: SETF (KTH-ELT LS 4)
 ;     (FUNCALL #'(SETF LISP-TRAINING::KTH-ELT) #:NEW1 #:LS608 4)
 ; ==>
 ;   (SB-C::%FUNCALL #'(SETF LISP-TRAINING::KTH-ELT) #:NEW1 
    #:LS608 4)
 ; 
 ; caught STYLE-WARNING:
    ;   undefined function: (SETF KTH-ELT)
    ; 
    ; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     (SETF KTH-ELT)
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition`

Comment: @AndrewS. That error says it's trying to call `(setf kth-elt)`, which implies you haven't evaluated `(defsetf kth-elt kth-upd)` yet.

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry i got it it wrong at first. So do I have to just put `(defsetf kth-elt kth-upd)` somewhere in the code and it will be set then?

Comment: @AndrewS. Yes. When you evaluate `defsetf`, somehow your implementation learns that `(setf kth-elt)` is in fact implemented by `kth-upd`. In your error message, you can see `#'(setf lisp-training::kth-elt)`, which is the function being looked for. Functions in CL can be named by symbols, as usual, but also using a `(setf <symbol>)` list. But that function was not yet defined in your case.

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum to coredump's answer, it's worth noting that the following works, and is, in my opinion, much better than using `defsetf`:

```
(defun kth-elt (lst k)
  (cond ((> 0 k) nil)
        ((= 0 k) (car lst))
        ((< 0 k) (kth-elt (cdr lst) (- k 1)))))

(defun (setf kth-elt) (new lst k)
  (cond ((> 0 k) nil)
        ((= 0 k) (setf  (car lst) new))
        ((< 0 k) (setf (kth-elt (cdr lst) (- k 1)) new))))
```

There are cases when you need `defsetf` but they are not that common.

(`kth-elt` itself is just a special-case of `elt` of course: in real life you don't need to write any of this.)